# intermediate points of BloodPresure from GoogleFit

Tags: google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I'm using this code to retrieve blood pressure data:

```
case DataBloodPresureRequest:
    return new DataReadRequest.Builder()
        .aggregate(HealthDataTypes.TYPE_BLOOD_PRESSURE, 
            HealthDataTypes.AGGREGATE_BLOOD_PRESSURE_SUMMARY)
        .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
        .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .enableServerQueries()
        .build();
```

I receive:

```
Data point:
    Type: com.google.blood_pressure.summary
    Start: 08.01.2019 01:51:02
    End: 08.01.2019 01:55:44
    Timestamp: 08.01.2019 01:55:44
    Field: blood_pressure_systolic_average Value: 202.5
    Field: blood_pressure_systolic_max Value: 205.0
    Field: blood_pressure_systolic_min Value: 200.0
    Field: blood_pressure_diastolic_average Value: 97.5
    Field: blood_pressure_diastolic_max Value: 100.0
    Field: blood_pressure_diastolic_min Value: 95.0
    Field: body_position Value: unset
    Field: blood_pressure_measurement_location Value: unset
```

08.01.2019 has two [data] points but I receive only max, min and s for the period.
I'd like to have the points like it's in GoogleFit app:

> data(08.01.2019 01:51:02) - value(200/95)
>
> data(08.01.2019 01:53:02) - value(205/95)

Data point has `startDate` and `endDate`, but has no intermediate points.

Answer (score 0):

You're explicitly requesting aggregated data points, via the `DataReadRequest.Builder.aggregate` call.

Use `read` instead.

Comment: if i use  return new DataReadRequest.Builder()
                        .read(HealthDataTypes.TYPE_BLOOD_PRESSURE)
                        .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                        .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                        .enableServerQueries()
                        .build();                                /n      recieve one point onStart period /n

Comment: Don't bucket by time. (I don't know if that'd fix it, but it doesn't make any sense to).

Comment: works without bucketsByTime but returns    ===                                                 Start: 11.12.2018 19:21:00
End: 11.12.2018 19:21:00
Field: blood_pressure_systolic Value: 130.0
Field: blood_pressure_diastolic Value: 81.0
Field: body_position Value: unset
Field: blood_pressure_measurement_location Value: unset  data at the beginning of December)))) My startTime=cal.set(2014, Calendar.OCTOBER, 28);      endTime= new Date(); I really dont understand why at the beginning of December;